# How to break and left align long lines of text in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tabulate

Trying to break long lines on '`;`' (semicolon) *AND* **left align** the output of that column

```py
# Python version 3.9.12.final.0
import pandas as pd  # Pandas version 1.4.2
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate
from IPython.display import HTML
    
# initialize list elements
long_field_data = [
    [10, "1_super_long_data textA textB textC;2_super_long_data textD textE textF;3_super_long_data textnothing"],
    [101, "2_super_long_data textA textB textJ;2_super_long_data textK textL textM;3_super_long_data textMoreNothing"],
    [1002, "3_super_long_data textA textB textW;2_super_long_data textX textY textZ;3_super_long_data LessThanNothing"],
]
        
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df_test = pd.DataFrame(long_field_data, columns=['cNameOne', 'Test Sequence'])
    
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
    
df_test
```

to get:
[image: Raw Data output visually]

I can break those lines on the semicolons:

```
display(HTML(df_test.to_html().replace(";","<br>")))
```

to get:

[image]

**But, I can't get them left-aligned.**
Tried:

```py
style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})         #FAILS

tabulate(df, showindex=False, headers=df.columns)     #FAILS (and not HTML, of course)

# various forms of:
df['Test Sequence'] = df['Test Sequence'].str.ljust(0)     # ALL FAIL
```

and many other `pretty_print()` functions, etc... **All FAIL**

**IS IT POSSIBLE** to get HTML output (or even textual output like Tabulate) with this column / series left-aligned?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
df_test["Test Sequence"] = df_test["Test Sequence"].str.replace(";", "<br>")

styles = [
    {"selector": "td", "props": [("text-align", "left")]}
]
df_test.style.set_table_styles(styles)
```

Output in a Jupyter notebook:

[image]